# True or false: For all subsets $ A $ and $ B $ of $ X $, if $ A \subseteq B $, then $ f[A] \subseteq f[B] $.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to determine if the following is true or false:

> For all subsets $ A $ and $ B $ of $ X $, if $ A \subseteq B $, then $ f[A] \subseteq f[B] $.

My guess is this would be true, because if $ A \subseteq B $, then $ f[A] \subseteq f[B] $.

Can anybody corroborate my understanding, or tell me where I may have gone wrong? All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you notice it's backwards? Why would both be true?

Comment: Sorry, the formatting was off, that is why it appeared backwards.  I fixed the formatting.  Very sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $A \subseteq B$. Let $y \in f(A)$. Then $\exists x \in A : f(x)=y$. But $A \subseteq B$, so if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$. Therefore, $\exists x \in B : f(x) = y$ so that  $y \in f(B)$ as required. We conclude that $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$.

Comment: Thank you!  This affirms what I thought, but in a much clearer way.  Many thanks for the help!

Comment: @OmarN Happy to help! :)